# Convert vector to integer

Tags: ruby, arrays, vector, multidimensional-array, narray

Knowing the multidimensional-array's shape of a vector, how can we convert it into a new vector of one dimension (by flatten the multidimensional-array)?

For example considering the following array:

```
arr = [
  [
    [ nil, nil ],
    [ nil, nil ],
    [ nil, nil ]
  ],
  [
    [ nil, nil ],
    [ nil, nil ],
    [ nil, nil ]
  ]
]

arr[0][0][0] = "A"
arr[1][0][1] = "B"

arr # =>
[
  [
    [ "A", nil ],
    [ nil, nil ],
    [ nil, nil ]
  ],
  [
    [ nil, "B" ],
    [ nil, nil ],
    [ nil, nil ]
  ]
]
```

...where `A` is the origin and `B` is the destination of the vector. Can write:

```
shape  = [2, 3, 2]
vector = [1, 0, 1]
```

From now, supposing we flatten `arr`, how could we translate the vector? In other words, how to translate this vector of 3 dimensions into a new one of 1 dimension?

This is a special case, because the origin of the vector is also the first coordinate of the array.  So we can found the result with:

```
arr.flatten.index("B") # => 7
```

Here's a another example with a 2D-array:

```
arr = [
  [ "A", nil ],
  [ "B", nil ],
  [ nil, nil ],
  [ nil, nil ],
  [ nil, nil ]
]
```

We can write this:

```
shape  = [2, 5]
vector = [1, 0]
```

And, once again,

```
arr.flatten.index("B") # => 2
```

But here is a more complicated example, with a negative vector:

```
arr = [
  [ "B", nil ],
  [ "A", nil ],
  [ nil, nil ],
  [ nil, nil ],
  [ nil, nil ]
]

shape  = [2, 5]
vector = [-1, 0]
```

How can the following method can be written ?

```
vector2index(shape, vector) # => -2
```

An example (simple) with a 1D-array:

```
arr = [ nil, "B", nil, nil, "A", nil, nil ]

shape  = [7]
vector = [-3]
vector2index(shape, vector) # => -3
```

Is there a simple way to flat a vector from an array of any dimensions? Thanks.

Comment: Can you please give a relevant link to explain the vector2index function.

Comment: Is there a simple way to explain your problem? Thanks.

Comment: @nightf0x & marc-andre-lafortune, thanks for your comments. I just rewritten my question, tried to be clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, assuming that first element of array is for X axis, second - for Y axis, third - for Z axis, you have a mistake in second and third example. Third example should be

```
shape  = [2,5]
vector = [0,-1]
vector2index(shape, vector) # => -2
```

And if first element of array is for Y axis, second - for X axis, then 2-nd and 3-rd examples is correct, but the first example is wrong.

If I understand the idea correctly, we need in first example multiply `vector[1]` to `shape[0]`, multiply `vector[2]` to `shape[0]*shape[1]` and then calculate sum of 3 elements. Generally, we don't need to multiply 0-th element, and we need to multiply n-th element to `shape[0]*shape[1]*...*shape[n-1]`.

You can implement it this way:

```
vector.each_with_index.map { 
  |v, i| i == 0? v: v * shape[0..i-1].inject(:*) 
}.inject(:+)
```

*Upd.* After you updated your question, it becomes more clear. If you want to preserve Ruby's indexing order, you need to reverse both arrays `shape` and `vector`.

```
vector.reverse.each_with_index.map { 
  |v, i| i == 0? v: v * shape[0..i-1].reverse.inject(:*) 
}.inject(:+)
```

Comment: Many thanks, @riateche. I'm currently watching your solution.
I confess that I have a doubt on the vector mistake; because logically, in the second example, the vector `AB` is equal to the coordinate of `B`.  However, this coordinate is `[1, 0]`, given the fact that `arr [1, 0] = "B"`.

Comment: After consideration, I think axes may be a matter of perspective.  For Ruby, (displaying an array of 2 dim) the X axis is vertical (and it goes down).  But for us humans, this vertical axis is by convention the Y axis.  For my needs, I would prefere to use your solution in the Ruby's perspective.  How could we update your implementation to do so?  Thanks again.

Comment: You need to reverse both arrays `shape` and `vector`. I've updated my answer.